# BackGround Color in Selenium RC?

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium.i want to assert the Background color of particular Screen.
How to assert Background color using Selenium rc?

Comment: from my point of view you can either get the attribute or make a screenshot and analyze the image (more effort for special cases)

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by retrieving the background color from the body. Should be something like this:

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
String color = body.getAttribute("bgcolor");
```

Comment: your ans seem to be OK for WebDriver (Selenium 2). But as I have understood Original poster is using Selenium RC

Comment: Sorry I don't know the equivalent for Selenium 1 since it isn't supported anymore maybe he should switch to webdriver.